# SSH authentication: (public key xor password) + google authenticator code

Tags: ssh, debian, pam, google-authenticator, two-factor-authentication

I'm using Debian bullseye. I'm trying to set up SSH two types logins:

1. password + code from Google's Authenticator (if user set it, "nullok" option),
2. public key + code from Google's Authenticator (if user set it, "nullok" option).

Type #1 works for me.
In type #2 I have public key + password (not public key passphrase) + code from GA. I added this line to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive keyboard-interactive
```

I'd like to user won't be prompted for password if key was supplied. Precisely, how to bypass pam_unix.so demand if public key was provided?

Is there any way to accomplish what I want on one machine? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The type #2 explanation is not clear to me. It sounds like the SSH key has a passphrase set or what password do you mean? Do you have a custom SSH or PAM config that requires a password even after a successful SSH auth?

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question and I added some info for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I solved it.

[CERN's PAM_2FA project](https://cern-cert.github.io/pam_2fa/) contains minor pam module: pam_ssh_user_auth.so. This module can tell PAM if there was any previously successful sshd authentications like public key (PAM_SUCCESS). So I made following changes in:

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes 
UsePAM yes 
AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive:pam publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam
```

/etc/pam.d/sshd:

```
auth    [success=2 ignore=ignore default=die]   pam_ssh_user_auth.so
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    [success=ok ignore=ignore default=bad]        pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
auth    required        pam_permit.so
```

It allows to skip prompt for password when public key was given.